trim a list of computer distinguished names
I need a little help manipulating the output of the following code
 $OUlists = get-adgroupmember -identity "Test-group" | select -ExpandProperty distinguishedname | sort distinguishedname
 $OUlists.Trimstart("OU")

the output of the script returns the full distinguished name of the systems and I need to drop everything before the first occurrence of "OU"
for example, the output is CN=Test,OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4
I need the output to be OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4
I have tried Trim, TrimStart, SPlit, substing and i cant manipulate my sting the way i need it to be.
one of the issues I encountered is that the character length in CN=Test varies depending on the computer name so i cant trim based on character count
I know its something simple I am overlooking and hoping someone can assist and point out my error.
thank you for your help in advance

You'll want to split the DN into its constituents parts (we call these relative distinguished names, or RDNs):
$DN = 'CN=Test,OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4'

$null,$trailingRDNs = $DN -split '(?<!\\),'

The assignment to $null will effectively discard the first RDN, and all we have to do now is join the remaining parts together again:
$parentDN = $trailingRDNs -join ','

$parentDN now contains the expected value.

For multiple objects, repeat the same operation on each iteration of ForEach-Object:
$OUs = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Test-group' |ForEach-Object {
  $DN = $_.DistinguishedName
  $null,$trailingRDNs = $DN -split '(?<!\\),'

  $parentDN = $trailingRDNs -join ','

  $parentDN
}

$OUs now contains all the parent DNs

that did work to a point.  the issue with the results is it created a long run on of results.  since the main script pulls all members of the test-group, when the join is done, it joins all of the RDNs together instead of keeping each one sperate and you end up with the following
OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4,OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4
what I am trying to end up with is
OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4
OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4

@NuckinFutz You just need to process one DN at a time, eg. Get-ADGroupMember |ForEach-Object { $DN = $_.distinguishedName; <# rest of sample code here, output $parentDN at the end #>}

sorry for the slow reply.  I did as you suggested and it worked, but it only outputs one OU ( the last OU in the array) but it is properly formatted the way i need
$OUlists = get-adgroupmember -identity "Test-group" | ForEach-Object -process {
$DN = $_.distinguishedname;
$null,$trailingRDNs = $DN -split '(?<!\),'
$parentDN = $trailingRDNs -join ','
}
$parentDN
output
OU=TestOU,OU=TestOU2,DC=Test,DC=Test1,DC=Test2,DC=Test3,DC=Test4

@NuckinFutz That's because you didn't output $parentDN at the end of the ForEach-Object block - you wait until after the last iteration. Move $ParentDN into the block and it'll work :)

Mathias R. Jessen
when putting the $parentDN inside the block it returns no results.
.............
$parentDN = $trailingRDNs -join ','
$parentDN
}
but if i add a write-host $parentDN then it does return everything i need exactly as i need it
thank you very much for your help and patience

@NuckinFutz I added a full example, please try it as-is :)

you can use $DN -split '(?<!\\),', 2 to avoid the -join

Another way would be to use a regex. The '?' turns off greedy, causing it to stop at the first occurrence of ,OU=.
$OUlists = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test-group" |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.DistinguishedName -match '^.*?,(OU=.*)$') { $Matches[1] }
    }


This would fail if the group was in a Container instead of an OU

@SantiagoSquarzon, you are probably right. This would do what the OP said. ... drop everything before the first occurrence of "OU"

Ah right. Well its what OP asked, he probably doesn't know groups can be below a Container. +1
